# Return data from API Python

Tags: python

Im trying to fetch data from a API and worked something out like this below.
I get the following error: response 200TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
I get this has to do with my API call but when i change str to int it doesnt solve the problem.
Could someone help me with this?

```
headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer xx"


total_results = []

for page_num in range(1, 7):
    # Build the URL and download the results
    url = "url" + str(page_num)
    print("Downloading", url)
    response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    total_results = total_results + data['results']


print("We have", len(total_results), "total results")
```

error:
Downloading xxx: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Traceback (most recent call last):

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Where is `data` defined? Also please provide the full traceback.

Comment: I don't understand. Your url is literally `URL1` through `URL6`, but I assume that is just for sample purposes. But then your are printing `response.status_code` before you even get the response. And why use `CaseInsensitiveDict`?

Comment: @CoryKramer i added the new code.

Comment: @theherk the print statement is just printing all the url's im reaching

Comment: Still would help to provide the full traceback, and the contents of `data`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: That isn't a full traceback, but since you provided you token, I got it. One moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you squared away:

```py
import requests

results = []
for page in range(1, 7):
    url = f"hxx={page}"
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer redacted",
    }
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        results.append(resp.json())

print(results)
```

Which yields a list as expected.

The full traceback in your scenario was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/h4s/projects/github.com/theherk/tmp-py/ws/./req.py", line 15, in <module>
    results.append(resp.json()["results"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Which helps us to see that the issue was that there was no key "results" in the response data. It was just a list.

Comment: thank you so much!
Could you edit the url please?

Comment: No problem, I approved the edit. But history shows both this and the token, so you should probably recycle your token. ... and consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark if it helped.